# Excel: How to create a dependent drop down list in Excel when the primary has duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, list, dropdown

I've researched several posts about dependent drop-down lists; however, I'm still stuck.  I need to create drop-down list based on a primary list that has duplicates.  Most of the examples have the data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuVJ4.jpg)oriented differently and are unique.

See the screenshot of the following table:

I want the primary drop down to show a non-duplicate list: e.g., cassette

THEN, I want the dependent list to show the drive options. e.g., clutch, vertilux motor, etc.

Best, Jason

Comment: What is your problem? Create a unique list? You could use a dictionary, or use a helper sheet, copy the relevant data and use the function "Remove duplicates".

Comment: I need a dependent drop down that will show a list based on a selection from COL_A.

See the 2nd answer below...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated to a more generic approach, to enable multiple lists as data sources.

Here's one way to do this - it relies on using a named range which refers to a VBA function: that function is called when you click a validation drop-down which refers to the name.

Needs a name defined (all the Data Validation lists point at this same name):
[image]

Lists sheet:
[image]

Data Entry sheet:
[image]

Code (all in a regular module):

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub Tester() 'for running the code in a debuggable way....
    Debug.Print getOptions().Address
End Sub


Function getOptions() As Range
    
    Dim c As Range, dict As Object, rw As Range, rngVals As Range, sz As Long
    
    Set rngVals = ListsSheet.Range("H4")
    rngVals.Resize(100).ClearContents   'clear previous options
    
    'On Error Resume Next                                                       'uncomment for debugging
    Set c = Application.Caller 'this function is called from the cell
                               '  where the drop-down is clicked
    'On Error GoTo 0                                                            'uncomment for debugging
    'If c Is Nothing Then Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry").Range("A4") 'uncomment for debugging
    Set rw = c.EntireRow
    
    Select Case c.Column                'whaich column is the dd in ?
        Case 1: Set dict = GetTypes()                    'no parent values
        Case 2: Set dict = GetColors(rw.Cells(1).Value)  'one parent value
        Case 3: Set dict = GetSizes(rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value) 'two parent values
        Case 5: Set dict = GetFinishes(rw.Cells(1).Value) 'Finishes depend on Type and are from a different list
        Case Else: Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End Select
    Debug.Print dict.Count
    
    If dict.Count > 0 Then 'any values to list out?
        rngVals.Cells(1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    End If
    sz = IIf(dict.Count = 0, 1, dict.Count)
    Set getOptions = rngVals.Resize(sz)   'return a range for the drop-down to reference

End Function

'returns the sheet with the lookup lists
Function ListsSheet() As Worksheet
    Set ListsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists")
End Function

'following 4 functions return different lists depending on source and filtering
Function GetTypes() As Object
    Set GetTypes = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange, 1)
End Function

Function GetColors(typ) As Object
    Set GetColors = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange, 2, 1, typ)
End Function

Function GetSizes(typ, clr) As Object
    Set GetSizes = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange, 3, 1, typ, 2, clr)
End Function

Function GetFinishes(typ) As Object
    Set GetFinishes = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange, 2, 1, typ)
End Function

'Given a range `rng`, return a scripting dictionary with all unique values from column# `valueCol`,
'  where (optionally) the row meets criteria supplied to `filters` (zero or more pairs of colNum, colValue)
Function Uniques(rng As Range, valueCol As Long, ParamArray filters() As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, arr, r As Long, c, filtering As Boolean
    Dim adding As Boolean, i As Long, colnum As Long, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    filtering = UBound(filters) <> -1
    arr = rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        adding = True      'by default we add...
        If filtering Then
            For i = LBound(filters) To UBound(filters) Step 2
                colnum = filters(i) 'column index to filter on
                v = filters(i + 1)  'value to filter on
                If arr(r, colnum) <> v Then
                    adding = False 'row did not match criteria
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        If adding Then dict(arr(r, valueCol)) = True
    Next r
done:
    Set Uniques = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Alright - I got it to work on my own! Thank you Tim!

Question: how would I set this code to clear if I went to say Option B and changed it?  I'd like it to reset Option C.

You rock!

Comment: For something like that you'd need to use the worksheet_change event - if an option is changed then all options to the right of it should be cleared.

Comment: how do I step through the code while it is executing? I added STOP and it blows right past it.

Comment: You can't step through a function which is called like this - best you can do is `debug.print` or maybe call the function from a sub (you will need to adjust the code for the case where there's no `Application.Caller` though)

Comment: got it.

So, I have one last obstacle to overcome.  I want to take the output of a dropdown and use it as input into doing the same thing.  Should I make a 2nd post?

Comment: Yes - I'm not sure what you're asking, so a new question would be better.

Comment: Posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957584/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-from-another-dependent-drop-down-in-excel-vb

Comment: My code above already dies that though?  If you're clicking on a dd for OptionB, it uses the selection from OptionA to filter the items for OptionB.

Comment: How would I do that from a secondary list?  That's the twist, 2 separate lists

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "two separate lists".  Will need a screenshot or some other illustration of what you're working with.

Comment: https://www.loom.com/share/ba119a3143d14356bcfbd7873e62ed12

Comment: OK I see now that's a bit more complex and it would make sense to split out the functionality which just returns a list of values (based on one or more other inputs).  I will mock something up and share it here.

Comment: See updated answer above - it's a bit different from my first code but more-flexible in its approach.