Dropdown list that is dependent on a cell that contains a delimiter string
I'll try to explain this the best I can. Basically, I have 'Categories' and 'Subcategories'. In the first column I would like to be able to select more than one Category from a dropdown list (I was able to figure this part out myself with some VBA coding but idk how to connect it to what I want to do next). In the second column, I would like what appears in the dropdown list to be dependent to was has been entered in the first column (also figured this part out). But I don't know how to make it so that the dropdown list in the second column gives the subcategories for all categories listed in the adjacent cell in column 1, and be able to select multiple subcategories from that dropdown list.
I have only been working on this with sample data, so this is what I have been using:



Categories
Subcategories




Fruit
Apple


Fruit
Banana


Fruit
Strawberry


Fruit
Blueberry


Fruit
Orange


Vegetable
Carrot


Vegetable
Celery


Vegetable
Spinach


Vegetable
Cucumber


Grains
Corn


Grains
Wheat


Grains
Rice



I followed a YouTube video (title: Dynamic Dependent Dropdown Lists in Excel: create and manage all the categories you need - T0032  by Cecilia Alves - Solve & Excel) to make the subcategory dropdown list dependent on the categories column. It would be more concise and simple if the you go watch the video rather than me trying to write down what the video shows.
And a YouTube video (title: How to Create A Multi-Select Drop-Down List in Excel by Sharon Smith) to be able to select multiple items from the category dropdown list. The VBA code I got and personalized from that video is:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 1 And (Target.Row >= 2 And Target.Row <= 21) Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Updated Code (On 'Data Entry' Sheet):
Sub Tester() 'for running the code in a debuggable way....
    Debug.Print getOptions().Address
End Sub
Function getOptions() As Range
    
    Dim c As Range, dict As Object, rw As Range, rngVals As Range, sz As Long
    
    Set rngVals = ListsSheet.Range("F6")
    rngVals.Resize(100).ClearContents   'clear previous options
    
    'On Error Resume Next                                                       'uncomment for debugging
    Set c = Application.Caller 'this function is called from the cell
                               '  where the drop-down is clicked
    'On Error GoTo 0                                                            'uncomment for debugging
    'If c Is Nothing Then Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry").Range("A4") 'uncomment for debugging
    Set rw = c.EntireRow
    
    Select Case c.Column                'whaich column is the dd in ?
        Case 1: Set dict = GetMainCategory()                    'no parent values
        Case 2: Set dict = GetSubcategory(rw.Cells(1).Value)  'one parent value - Finishes depend on Type and are from a different list
        Case Else: Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End Select
    Debug.Print dict.Count
    
    If dict.Count > 0 Then 'any values to list out?
        rngVals.Cells(1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    End If
    sz = IIf(dict.Count = 0, 1, dict.Count)
    Set getOptions = rngVals.Resize(sz)   'return a range for the drop-down to reference
End Function
'returns the sheet with the lookup lists
Function ListsSheet() As Worksheet
    Set ListsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists")
End Function
'following 4 functions return different lists depending on source and filtering
Function GetMainCategory() As Object
    Set GetMainCategory = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange, 1)
End Function
Function GetSubcategory() As Object
    Set GetSubcategory = Uniques(ListsSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange, 2, 1, typ)
End Function
'Given a range `rng`, return a scripting dictionary with all unique values from column# `valueCol`,
'  where (optionally) the row meets criteria supplied to `filters` (zero or more pairs of colNum, colValue)
Function Uniques(rng As Range, valueCol As Long, ParamArray filters() As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, arr, r As Long, c, filtering As Boolean
    Dim adding As Boolean, i As Long, colnum As Long, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    filtering = UBound(filters) <> -1
    arr = rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        adding = True      'by default we add...
        If filtering Then
            For i = LBound(filters) To UBound(filters) Step 2
                colnum = filters(i) 'column index to filter on
                v = filters(i + 1)  'value to filter on
                If arr(r, colnum) <> v Then
                    adding = False 'row did not match criteria
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        If adding Then dict(arr(r, valueCol)) = True
    Next r
done:
    Set Uniques = dict
End Function


I don't think that dependent dropdown approach will work with multiple selections in the "Categories" column - you'd need a more-flexible approach, maybe using VBA to create the drop-down list source - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914677/excel-how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel-when-the-primary-has-du/72918785#72918785

Too much to post here but there's an example workbook here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vabIQHXrPUhnaZryGF1wfvbQr5gV6eEy/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106591725375141807281&rtpof=true&sd=true

Sounds like you want a listbox and then a second listbox to generate its list based on the contents of the first listbox.

This is super helpful! Thanks Tim :) What formula did you use for the dynamic list? it isn't showing up in the example workbook for whatever reason

There is no formula - the list is created using VBA in response to clicking on the cell drop-down.  Similar to my answer in the linked post above.

@TimWilliams I updated my post to include the code you provided in the linked post. I tried my best to personalize it to my sample data but I can't get it to work. Do you have any suggestions?

@TimWilliams sent! thank you!!

Check my email reply - might have gone to your spam folder
